# Do you have to have bitcoin core fully downloaded (150gb+) in order to run a lightning node?

Tags: bitcoin-core, nodes, lightning-network

Looking to setup a lightning node, but what are the EXACT requirements? Do you have to install bitcoin core and fully have the blockchain downloaded of 150gb+?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

A lightning node needs a way to refer a copy of the blockchain that it trusts, so the node can either have it locally **or** might refer to one using neutrino. That would allow you to run it without an external hard drive at all. You could run a lightning node on a rpi off just an ssd card by this method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to be able to query every transaction within the whole blockchain. Two ways to achieve that:

- Run your own full node (with transaction indexing [txindex=1] and no pruning), that requires about 200 GB to store everything (see my [Raspberry Pi guide](https://github.com/Stadicus/guides/blob/master/raspibolt/README.md) for additional information)
- Trust a remote Bitcoin node to tell you the truth, eg. using [Neutrino](https://github.com/lightninglabs/neutrino/blob/master/README.md). This will be the enabler for all mobile applications and is currently tested on Bitcoin testnet. No mainnet release yet.